# MySQL Date_Sub issue while deleting from database (using variables)

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, shell, variables

I'm trying to save the result of a select query to a file and then truncate that database table. 
For the backup I run a query which uses a shell variable to determine how many days I need the backup for and it works fine, I get a file saved, works exactly as I want it to.

```
SET @sql_text = CONCAT ( "SELECT * FROM databasename.tablename WHERE (datetimestamp < (NOW()) AND datetimestamp > (DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL ",$daysback," DAY))) into outfile 'filename-" , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H%i') , ".csv'" , "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " , "LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ");
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;
DROP PREPARE s1;
```

the value for daysback comes from the shell script (user input).
Okay so that part works.

Now when I try to do something on the same lines for deleting old entries, it just doesn't work..

```
SET @sql_text = CONCAT("DELETE FROM databasename.tablename WHERE datetimestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ",$daysret," DAY)");
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;
DROP PREPARE s1;
```

again the variable daysret here comes from the script and value is correct, I'm certain, tried echoing the value of both variables before entering the MySQl shell..

Further I also tried

```
Set @daysret1=$daysret;
SELECT @daysret1 ;
```

and I get the correct value for daysret1 indicating that the value of daysret is also correct. also tried using @daysret1 in the query directly, but even that didn't help.
I have tried various variations of double quotes and what not in that delete statement but it just won't do its job. Works fine if I use a number directly (no variable), so the command is good, its just something to do with the variable itself.

Also if there is a syntax error then MySql actually shows the error (ran into some of those while playing around with the quotes, commas etc. in that query), but in the command I posted above, nothing happens, the script hangs, and nothing is deleted from the database.

Please help!

PS: If there is a better way of doing it then I'm all ears..currently these statements are running inside a block like this..

```
mysql -u$user -p$pass << EOF
....
....
EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `CONCAT` or `PREPARE` in the second case it can be simply:

```
mysql -u$user -p$pass <<EOF
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE datetimestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $daysret DAY)
EOF
```

However, it looks to me like the query you have should work. Are you sure there are rows that match the `WHERE` condition? You're using a different shell variable in the two queries: the first one uses `$daysback`, the second uses `$daysret`. So just because the first one returns rows doesn't mean the second will find something to delete.

Another way you can write it is:

```
mysql -u$user -p$pass -e "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE datetimestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $daysret DAY)"
```

An advantage of this is that you can put `set -x` in your script, and it will show the line before it's executed, with the variable substituted. Than you can see if there's a problem with the variable.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that as well, didn't work (started off without CONCAT for delete). If I use a value, lets say 45 instead of daysret, that would work fine (both with and without concat), I would see the table size going down and entries being deleted, I have a test database I'm trying this on. So basically what I'm trying to say is, in the exact same query if I use an actual value it would work fine and that is the value I am trying to pass using this variable now.

Comment: You're missing the database argument to `mysql` -- do you have a default database specified in `.my.cnf`?

Comment: In trying to change the tablename before posting, I edited the original code, I'm actually using databasename.tablename in the query. Edited the original post.

Comment: Not using any quotes or commas around the variable finally worked, although I still don't see the difference but anyhow it works now. Thanks for you help :)